# MySql set charset for ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, character-encoding

I am using the MySql class in ruby with MySql.real_connect etc.
Is there a method to set the mysql charset just like mysql_set_charset in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET NAMES charset` query always works, even in PHP. No need for any special function